# Post Type Support Array Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types

I am attempting to remove support from a post type, but I can't get the array to work.

I can get the string to work --

`remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'editor' );`

but not this array --

`remove_post_type_support( 'product', array( 'editor','product_cat' ) );`

nor even this array --

`remove_post_type_support( 'product', array( 'editor' ) );`

**FULL CODE**

`add_action( 'init', 'modify_product_type' );
function modify_product_type() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'product', array('editor','product_cat'));
}`

Comment: Which hook do you use? Please post a bit more code to see. Is 'product' maybe a typo. Do you try to remove the support before the post type is registered maybe?

Comment: @websupporter The first piece of code works perfectly when using a string. It's the array that's not working for some reason.

Comment: did update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_post_type_support()` doesn't support arrays. You have to unregister each feature separately.

See:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1746